# Why `NERDTree` doesn't trigger the autocommand `BufEnter`?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-nerdtree

I am writing a vimscript function which should keep in a consistent state a "home made buffer manager". The idea is that I want to keep a trace of my buffers in the tabs they were open in.

This "buffer manager" simply is a dictionary which has the numbers of the tabs as keys and lists of buffers numbers as values.

To add the different buffers to this dictionary I created the following autocommand:

```
autocmd! BufEnter * call AddBufferToTab()
```

And then I have my function:

```
function! AddBufferToTab()
    let newBufNr = bufnr("%") 

    " create an entry for the current tab if necessary
    if !has_key(g:BuffersManager, tabpagenr())
        let  g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()] = []
    endif

    " Add the buffer to the tab
    if buflisted(newBufNr) && index(g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()], newBufNr) == -1
        call add (g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()],newBufNr)
    endif
endfunction
```

When vim enters a buffer the function is called, an empty list is created if the tab wasn't already managed.

Then I test if the buffer is listed by `:ls` with `buflisted(newBufNr)` and if the buffer is already in the list of the tab.

It is important to note that the first test seems to work: I don't want to add buffers which are not listed by `:ls` and when I open an help buffer for example, the buffer is not added

The function seems to work properly excepted for one use case:

When I open NERDTree with `:NERDTree` or `:NERDTreeToggle` the function doesn't seems to be executed *(at least the debug `echom` that I used never appeared)* and the buffer still end added to the manager.

Note that when I add

```
echom "ADD " . bufnr("%") . "  " . bufname("%") . "  " . buflisted(bufnr("%"))
```

To the function the informations seems to be the good ones (the ones of the currently entered buffer).

I also checked that NERDTree buffer have their property `buflisted` to 0.

I have been working on this problem for several days now and I really can't figure out what's happening.

**TL;DR** Why NERDTree buffers are added to the dictionary when the function is meant to ignore `nobuflisted` buffers?

**NOTE** If ones wants a big picture of the problem the function is a part of a plug-in I'm developing and which is available on [github](https://github.com/statox/bettertabs.vim)

**NOTE 2** Of course if someone needs any additional information I'll gladly add them to this question, ask in the comments.

---

**Additional information**

I followed the comment of @VanLaser and splitted the `if` condition and based my test also on the name of the buffer. I also added some debugging message, here is the function in "debugging state":

```
function! AddBufferToTab()
    let newBufNr = bufnr("%") 

    " create an entry for the current tab if necessary
    if !has_key(g:BuffersManager, tabpagenr())
        let  g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()] = []
    endif

    " Get conditions to add the tab
    let isListed = buflisted(newBufNr)

    let isAlreadyInManager = 1
    if (index(g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()], newBufNr) == -1)
        let isAlreadyInManager = 0
    endif

    let isNERDTreeBuffer = 0
    if (bufname("%") =~ "NERD_Tree_")
        let isNERDTreeBuffer = 1
    endif

    " Debugging messages
    echom bufname("%")
    if (isListed)
        echom "is Listed"
    else 
        echom "is not Listed"
    endif

    if (isAlreadyInManager)
        echom "is AlreadyInManager"
    else 
        echom "is not AlreadyInManager"
    endif

    if (isNERDTreeBuffer)
        echom "is NERDTreeBuffer"
    else 
        echom "is not NERDTreeBuffer"
    endif
    echom "========="

    " Add the buffer to the tab
    if isListed && !isAlreadyInManager && !isNERDTreeBuffer
        call add (g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()],newBufNr)
    endif
endfunction
```

I am sure that I don't have a call to the `add` function anywhere else than in this function.

I then followed this workflow:

- sourcing the file, the buffer manager is empty
- `:e %` (add the current file to the manager)
- `:e $MYVIMRC`
- `:NERDTree`
- select the first file `betterTabs.vim` in NERDTree.

And here is the log I had:

[image]

As you can see the opening of NerdTree doesn't seem to trigger the function (since I don't have any message about it in the log) BUT when I output the content of my dictionnary I get:

[image]

As I said I don't have any other call to `add` in my whole file (I gave sooner in the post the link to the github repo if anyone wants to check).

I don't understand how the buffer can be added when it doesn't even trigger the function.

---

**More infos to follow the investigations of @VanLaser in the comments** (many thanks to him):

First, to quote [`:h ls`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:ls):

> Each buffer has a unique number.  That number will not change,
>   so you can always go to a specific buffer with `:buffer N` or
>   `N CTRL-^`, where N is the buffer number.

So in theory if I get the number of the buffer I'm using it shouldn't change in the future.

Also I added the following lines at the very beginning of my function:

```
echom bufnr('%')
echom expand('<abuf>')

if bufnr('%') != expand('<abuf>')
    echom "RETURN"
    return
endif
```

and with the same workflow I get the same results, also I checked that the buffer numbers was the good ones:

Here is the output of `messages`:

[image]

The output of `ls!`:

[image]

And finally the content of my dictionary:

[image]

As you can see it seems that the numbers are correctly returned, but once again NERDTree is launched but doesn't trigger the function.

---

**More infos to follow the comments of @lcd047**

I changed the autocommand to

```
autocmd! BufEnter * call AddBufferToTab(expand('<abuf>'))
```

The function prototype to

```
function! AddBufferToTab(bufNumber)
```

and I replaced `let newBufNr = bufnr("%")` with `let newBufNr = a:bufNumber` and the behavior gets even weirder:

I added after the assignation of `newBufNr` the following debugging echos:

```
echom newBufNr
echom bufnr('%')
echom expand('<abuf>')
echom a:bufNumber
```

For every buffers they show the same number (so using `<abuf>` in the autocommand doesn't make a difference in the cases I tried).

**But** it get even weirder because then every buffers appears as not listed: for a reason that I don't understand `buflisted(expand('<abuf>'))` returns 0 for every buffers.

---

**PS** I'm sorry for the length of this post I'm just trying to give as much informations as possible because I really absolutely don't understand what's happening there.

Comment: Are you NerdTree buffers truly unlisted? Check `:ls!`. Do you get `0` when do `:echo buflisted(bufnr('%'))` inside the NerdTree buffer? You may also want to use `has_key(g:MyDic, newBufNr)`. See `:h has_key`. Maybe it would be best to use `expand('<abuf>')` in your autocmd calls. See `:h <abuf>`

Comment: As I said in my question I debugged the buflisted property of nerdtree buffers and I confirm that the value of `buflisted(bufnr('%'))` for nerdtree buffers is 0. Also I didn't know `:ls!` but I get a `u` in front of those buffers, so know I'm really sure they are unlisted :-) Thanks for your other advices I'll definitely check them!

Comment: I don't have NERDTree installed, so ... but if I can suggest another approach: leave the NERDTree buffers listed, and filter buffer addition in current tab list by the buffer's *name*. Also if you split the `if` in 2 parts, and assign those parts, each, to a variable, then you can check their values before the condition (`if nonlisted && unmanaged ...`).

Comment: @VanLaser: I thought of filtering the buffers according to their name but I think that might be less robust than the `buflisted` parameter: for now I've had problem only with NerdTree, but I'm not sure I will not have the same issue with another plugin and adding a condition for each case might be not very convenient. But if I don't find another solution that's probably what I'll do. Also yes when I'm debugging I split the `if` I put it back together for the question.

Comment: Perhaps you add a buffer number for a certain buffer, but afterwards that number points to *another* buffer (e.g. the NERDTree one) - which would suggest some add/delete management issues (de-sync).

Comment: Might be tricky getting the right buffer number: see [this](https://github.com/Shougo/tabpagebuffer.vim/blob/master/plugin/buffer.vim#L42) with [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/AvQROAIUnSQ/1bZseM7YObwJ)

Comment: @VanLaser: thank you very much for your comments. I edited my answer to show the new results following your advises.

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but try passing `<abuf>` from the `autocmd` to get the buffer that triggered `BufEnter`, rather than inferring it from `%`.  Contrary to the popular belief (and to the common sense), `autocmd`s are _not_ guaranteed to refer to the current buffer.  Also, they are not triggered in a logical order, so maybe your function queries `buflisted()` before NERDTree gets to hide the buffer.

Comment: @lcd047: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question to explain what I've done but the tl;dr version is: the buffer numbers are the same than with the previous version and now all buffers appears as not listed. The more I try new things the more I get confused with the behavior of this function.

Comment: `<abuf>` is only valid in `autocmd` lines.  Also, buffer functions make a difference between strings and numbers.  This is a common pitfall, because buffer numbers can get implicitly converted to strings, and `buflisted("2")` is very different from `buflisted(2)`.  For this reason, it's always a good idea to call `str2nr()` when you want buffer numbers, even when you don't see any obvious reason why the argument might have been converted to a string. :) In particular, try `str2nr(expand('<abuf>'))` instead of just `expand('<abuf>')`.  Tests like `type(buf) == type(0)` are also a good idea.

Comment: @lcd047: Good to know for the conversion: I had read in [`:h 41.2`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html) that `Vim automatically converts a string to a number when it is looking for a number.  When using a string that doesn't start with a digit the resulting number is zero.` so that is a little bit misleading. Now when modifying the autocommand to `autocmd! BufEnter * call AddBufferToTab(str2nr(expand('<abuf>')))` the listed/not listed are seen properly but the behavior is still the same: NerdTree buffers are added even if the function doesn't output the debugging messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You cannot filter the buffer at its creation, you should wait until you have 
more informations.

## First attempt

I used the `:debug NERDTree` command to see all the calls that this function
makes. When trying to stop it before the end I noticed something : A buffer was
created, without name, without filetype. And it had the position/size of the
nerdtree buffer (left split about 20 columns width).

It got me thinking that maybe you are trying to filter a buffer before it get's
enough informations. So the buffer doesn't *know* that it will be a nerdtree
buffer yet.

## Second attempt

Instead of debugging manually I did a little log function that allows me to see
the flow of events when calling `:NERDTree` :

```
augroup DebugGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufAdd      * :call s:Debug('BufAdd')
  autocmd BufCreate   * :call s:Debug('BufCreate')
  " idem for BufDelete BufWipeout BufFilePre BufFilePost BufEnter BufLeave BufWinEnter
  "          BufWinLeave BufUnload BufHidden BufNew FileType Syntax
augroup END

function! s:Debug(message) abort
  silent execute '!echo '.a:message.' '.bufnr("%").' >> debug'
endfunction
```

Sample result :

```
BufNew 1
BufAdd 1
BufCreate 1
BufLeave 1
BufEnter 5
BufWinEnter 5
BufDelete 5
BufWipeout 5
BufUnload 5
BufNew 5
BufAdd 5
BufCreate 5
BufEnter 5
BufWinEnter 5
BufDelete 5
Syntax 5
FileType 5
```

You can see here that the buffer `1` is the original buffer and the `5` is the
nerdtree one. And to create the nerdtree buffer, there are : two times the
events `BufEnter`, `BufDelete` and `BufWinEnter`. It's kind of strange why
nerdtree needs to open and delete two times the buffer to get working (but I'm
sure they have a good reason).

## Third attempt

This time I used the methods that you provide in your script and in your
question to add details to the log :

```
function! s:DebugBuffer(event)
    let newBufNr = bufnr("%")
    let isListed = buflisted(newBufNr)
    let isAlreadyInManager = (index(g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()], newBufNr) == -1)?0:1
    let isNERDTreeBuffer = (bufname("%") =~ "NERD_Tree_")?1:0
    let newBufSyntax = &ft

    call s:Debug('"'.a:event.' ['.newBufNr.'/'.bufname("%").' '.newBufSyntax.'] listed : '.isListed.' / managed : '.isAlreadyInManager.' / NERDTree '.isNERDTreeBuffer.'"')
    call s:Debug('"=> '.isListed.' & '.!isAlreadyInManager.' & '.!isNERDTreeBuffer.'"')
endfunction

augroup BuffersManagerGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufAdd      * :call s:DebugBuffer('BufAdd')
  autocmd BufCreate   * :call s:DebugBuffer('BufCreate')
  " idem for BufDelete BufWipeout BufFilePre BufFilePost BufEnter BufLeave BufWinEnter
  "          BufWinLeave BufUnload BufHidden BufNew FileType Syntax
augroup END

function! s:Debug(message) abort
  silent execute '!echo '.a:message.' >> debug'
endfunction
```

The syntax is the following :

```
Event [BufferNumber/Filename FileType] listed : isListed / managed : isManaged / NERDTree : isNERDTree
=> litteral condition to be tested
```

The `isNERDTree` is checked using the name, as you did in your question.

The log is :

```
BufNew [4/betterTabs.vim vim] listed : 1 / managed : 0 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 1 & 1
BufAdd [4/betterTabs.vim vim] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufCreate [4/betterTabs.vim vim] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufLeave [4/betterTabs.vim vim] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufEnter [5/ ] listed : 1 / managed : 0 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 1 & 1
BufWinEnter [5/ ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufDelete [5/ ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufWipeout [5/ ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufUnload [5/ ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 0
=> 1 & 0 & 1
BufNew [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 1 & 0 & 0
BufAdd [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 1 & 0 & 0
BufCreate [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 1 & 0 & 0
BufEnter [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 1 & 0 & 0
BufWinEnter [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 1 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 1 & 0 & 0
BufDelete [5/NERD_tree_1 ] listed : 0 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 0 & 0 & 0
Syntax [5/NERD_tree_1 nerdtree] listed : 0 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 0 & 0 & 0
FileType [5/NERD_tree_1 nerdtree] listed : 0 / managed : 1 / NERDTree 1
=> 0 & 0 & 0
```

Here you can clearly see something : the new buffer (number 5) does not get
noticed by the `isNERDTree` condition when triggering the `BufEnter` event, in fact it is not a nerdtree buffer yet.
Later, on triggering the `BufNew` event its name change (but not its filetype).

Based on your primary conditions :

```
if isListed && !isAlreadyInManager && !isNERDTreeBuffer
    call add (g:BuffersManager[tabpagenr()],newBufNr)
endif
```

The add get called only one time : on the `BuffEnter` (notice the `1 & 1 & 1`).
When called on `BufEnter`, the buffer is added to the list, but after, because
it already got considered, it doesn't change.

Once you know this you can do multiple things :

1. On events, you check if the buffer should be removed, like so :

new condition :

```
if isListed && isAlreadyInManager && isNERDTreeBuffer
  " should be removed
endif
```

2. You can use a different condition, instead of checking the name. As listed in
   my log, you can recognize for the filetype and on the `FileType` event delete
   the buffer.

## Conclusion

For the nerdtree plugin, you should double check the *validity* of the
buffer. As you cannot filter the buffer on it's creation, you should wait for
another event to remove the new buffer if needed.

**Notes** :

- Sorry for the long post, I wanted to be thorough.
- If you want more details, feel free to ask, I'll be happy to add them.

Comment: Nice and complete answer, thanks for the deep investigation! I'll probably see to add the double check + remove mechanism.

Comment: I'm trying to override the behavior of the J and K binds in nerdtree, as they are overridden by nerdtree to hop to the top and bottom of a directory. obviously the BufEnter map doesn't work, though it does after i switch out of and back into the nerdtree window. Is there a way to do this on the first open without lots of awful scripting?