# Reopen splits after closing them with <C-w>o

Tags: vim-windows, split

I majorly use vim over an ssh session using putty. Sometimes I may have to copy code from ssh in a vim session but it's not very convenient. I do the following :

```
<C-w>o
:set nu!
```

This close all splits that I have.

Is there a way just for me to expand the current window to the whole screen temporarily and recover all closed splits afterward?

Comment: Could you give some screen shots so we can see how it 'breaks' your layout please ? :)

Comment: @Nobe4 the layout is random. i split windows all the time. by having `<C-w>o` only current window remains, so i lost the view of multiple files. i am expecting recover to whatever layout after i copy the text i need

Comment: you could define a function that cleans your display and another one that restores it ... Have you tried searching this way ? Writing vim function is an excellent way to learn :)

Comment: @Nobe4 but how. i know it's not a one command existing solution but i will need a guideline at least.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a safer way to do what you are currently doing:

```
:tabe %|set nonu
```

Once you are done, close that tab page with `:q` to go back to the previous tab page.

--- edit ---

A similar workflow for transient buffers:

```
:tabnew|set nonu|b#
```

--- endedit ---

That said, you should probably try "X forwarding" which allows you to share clipboard over the wire:

```
$ ssh -X ...
```

See `$ man ssh`.

Comment: thanks. i see the sense here. btw, sorry for the confusion, but i really meant using putty.

Comment: PuTTY can do X forwarding: http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a way to do that with an unwritten buffer? (I can use `%` if the buffer wasn't written once before). Also +1 for X forwarding.

Comment: @statox, you can use `:tabnew|b#`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sessions if you don't feel like creating a function ([`:h view-sessions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions))

Before closing your splits simple do

```
:mksession ~/tmp.session
```

This will save the current layout in the file `~/tmp.session` (of course you can change the file path)

Then expand your window as you usually do and then use:

```
:source ~/tmp.session
```

which will restore the layout saved in the file.

---

Also you can even simplify it, knowing that without argument `:mksession` will create the file `~/Session.vim` you can do the following:

```
nnoremap <key> :mksession<CR> :only<CR>
```

This mapping will save your session and "maximize" the current window.

Then create this mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :source ~/Session.vim<CR>
```

to easily get your session back.

---

**EDIT** In the comments HuStmpHrr mentionned an issue with `:mksession` and `NERDTree`. Actually the problem comes from the way `NERDTree` creates its buffers: from what I have understood it actually creates a buffer, do some stuff, delete this buffer and create another one and do some stuff again (see [this nobe4 answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4377/1841) mentionning this).

In my opinion the wiser is to do more or less like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590615/4194289): closing NERDTree before making a session and opening it after restoring it.

A workaround could then be to create these functions:

```
function! MyMkSession(filePath)
    NERDTreeClose
    execute "mksession! " . a:filePath
endfunction

function! MySoSession(filePath)
    execute "source " . a:filePath
    NERDTree
endfunction
```

And to use them instead of the built-in ones. That is neither clean or elegant but that could do the job.

Comment: i have problems with `mksession` since i use nerdtree. i have problems with general session managers, because these managers try to preserve all my key bindings, autocmds, commands, etc. however i don't really need. is there a nice way just to remember the layout of windows?

Comment: Uh I've struggled more than once with NerdTree on different topics, I'll see if I can find a workaround ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As guidelines, I would do something like :

```
let splits={}

function! Clean()
  " Populate splits with the current splits
endfunction

function! Restore()
  " Restore the splits from the variable splits
endfunction
```

You can look at `:h usr_41.txt` that contains a lot of function you can call to get all informations you need.

e.g.

```
bufname()       get the name of a specific buffer
...
winheight()     get height of a specific window
winwidth()      get width of a specific window
...
```

You can look up for dictionnaries here `:h 'dictionary'`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Plugin *ZoomWin*

by *Charles Campbell*

This plugin remaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to do both: maximize and restore previous layout.

This plugin can be downloaded from two locations

- https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508 (v24)
- http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ZOOMWIN (v25)